# Attiny85 uploading error

Tags: usb, attiny, avr, attiny85, programmer

I am getting an error while trying to upload programs to the Attiny85 through a USBTinyISP programmer, found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FDD4EP0). Unfortunately, it isn't working. Following [this](https://shallowsky.com/blog/hardware/attiny85-c.html) tutorial for connecting the board and [this](https://wolles-elektronikkiste.de/en/programming-attiny85-84-45-44-25-24) tutorial for programming it with the Arduino IDE. My code is:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

A picture of my setup, which I checked at least 10 times:

[image: setup]

However, I get this error message:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jun 22 2016 at 16:05:21
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : usb
     Using Programmer              : usbtiny
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found USBtinyISP, bus:device: bus-0:\\.\libusb0-0001--0x1781-0x0c9f
         AVR Part                      : ATtiny85
         Chip Erase delay              : 400000 us
         PAGEL                         : P00
         BS2                           : P00
         RESET disposition             : possible i/o
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                              Block Poll               Page                       Polled
       Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
       ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
       eeprom        65    12     4    0 no        512    4      0  4000  4500 0xff 0xff
       flash         65     6    32    0 yes      8192   64    128 30000 30000 0xff 0xff
       signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
       lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
       calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

     Programmer Type : USBtiny
     Description     : USBtiny simple USB programmer, http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/
avrdude: programmer operation not supported

avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

An error occurred while uploading the sketch
avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Can someone please help me to fix this problem?
Thank you.

P.S.: On a website that talked about this error message and a similar programmer said to take out a jumper. I took out the only jumper on the programmer and it did not affect the error message.

UPDATE:
I changed the support from "attiny" by David 0 Mellis to "ATTinyCore" by SpenceKonde. Here is a screenshot of my tools menu:

[image: tools menu]

Now I get a different error:

```
    avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jun 22 2016 at 16:05:21
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\loydn\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-master\avr/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM3
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 2400
         Setting bit clk period        : 5.0
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM3": The system cannot find the file specified.



avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

FIX!!!:
It turns out that it was a problem with the programmer. By connecting the Attiny85 to the 10-pin header instead of the 6-pin one, it was able to upload successfully.

Comment: Look at the last lines of the output, and do what it says ```Double check connections and try again```, also it would be preferable to not connect anything to certain pins on your board.

Please add your code used.

Comment: The code is a simple serial sketch. Also, I am not connecting anything to the chip.

Comment: Answers should be posted as answers, not as part of the question :) Glad you worked it out, though. Unrelated, but there's no way to understand what your setup is from that picture. Consider using Fritzing or even a hand-drawn schematic instead. I just see a fuzzy pile of wires and a chip in a breadboard.